# Difference between $( (a,b), c )$ and $( a, (b,c) )$ following Kuratowski's definition of ordered pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the exercise 2.1.6 of *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek & Jech it is asked of the reader to find an example of $( (a,b), c ) \neq ( a, (b,c) )$.
The book defines ordered triples as $ (a,b,c) = ( (a,b), c)$, therefore I'm compelled to say that they are never equal: when I expand the terms I get

$$ ( (a,b), c) = \{ \{ \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \} \}, \{ \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \} , c \}\} $$

$$ ( a, (b,c) ) = \{ \{a\}, \{ a, \{ \{b\}, \{b,c\} \} \} \} $$

Am I interpreting correctly how it defines ordered triples (or quadruples)?

Comment: Obviously $((a,b),c)=(a,(b,c))$ would imply both $(a,b)=a$ and $c=(b,c)$. If all sets are required to be well-founded (as in ZFC), neither can be the case no matter which representation of pairs you use.

Comment: @celtschk that's a good point, thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, but you will need the Axiom of Regularity to prove it (which is treated later in the book, I believe).

The Axiom of Regularity makes it impossible that there exists a set $x$ such that $x= \{x\}$. Without it we cannot prove that such a set $x=\{x\}$ does not exist. It is then impossible to prove that $((a,b),c)\neq(a,(b,c))$, since if we take $a=b=c$ and let $a=\{a\}$, we get:

\begin{align}
((a,b),c)&=((a,a),a)\\
&=(\{\{a\}\},a)\\
&=(\{a\},a)\\
&=(a,a)\\
&=(a,\{a\})\\
&=(a,\{\{a\}\})\\
&=(a,(a,a))=(a,(b,c))
\end{align}

---

On the other hand, if we can use the Axiom of Regularity, then by using that $(a,b)=(a',b')$ if and only if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$ we would get that $((a,b),c)=(a,(b,c))$ implies $a=(a,b)$ and $c=(b,c)$. We have contradiction with the Axiom of Regularity, since $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=a$ would imply $\{a\}\in a$.